# Handling focus in react native with multiple input

Tags: react-native, state

I am looking to only toggle the focus state on one of the inputs instead of both when onFocus is fired.

With both inputs having the 'onFocus' and 'onBlur' events I was expecting the state to update on only the current element that is focussed.

Should I be using refs instead of state for this sort of event handling?

```
class SignInScreen extends Component {

state = {
  isFocused: false,
  style: {
    inputContainer: styles.input
  }
}

onFocus = () => {

    if(!this.state.isFocused) {
      this.setState({
        isFocused: true,
        style: {
          inputContainer: styles.inputDifferent
        }
      })
    }
  }
  onBlur = () => {
    if(this.state.isFocused) {
      this.setState({
        isFocused: false,
        style: {
          inputContainer: styles.input
        }
      })
    }
}
render() {
    return (
      <Input
            containerStyle={[styles.input, this.state.style.inputContainer]}      
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
          />
          <Input
            containerStyle={[styles.input, this.state.style.inputContainer]}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
          />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white,
    marginBottom: 16,
    maxWidth: '90%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto'
  },
  inputDifferent: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code Like This:

Edited:

```
    class SignInScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    isFocused: false,
    firstLoad: true

  }   

  onFocus = () => {
        this.setState({
          isFocused: !this.state.isFocused,
          firstLoad: false
        })
    }

  render() {
    const {isFocused} = this.state
      return (
        <View>
        <Input
              containerStyle={isFocused || firstLoad ? styles.input : styles.inputDifferent}      
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
            />
            <Input
              containerStyle={!isFocused  || firstLoad ? styles.input : styles.inputDifferent}
              onFocus={this.onFocus}
            />
         </View>
      )
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'white',
      marginBottom: 16,
      maxWidth: '90%',
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto'
    },
    inputDifferent: {
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
    }  
  });
```

its unnecessary to include styles on state. it is better to only use this.state.isFocus to make code simplier. just used this to make a condition on what style the inputs will be using.

you can also disregard onBlur. because all we need on the conditions is isFocus.

the key factor here is the exclamation symbol that will make the state toggle.

Edited: firstLoad state added to make the style of both inputs the same on load. that will be used on the condition inside input styles.

note: it can only work with two inputs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion although when I implement this, focussing on the first input field also focusses the second input field and vice versa.

Comment: Also when navigating away from the input field it still keeps the focussed styles which is why I thought the onBlur event was also needed.

Comment: did you already add exclamation symbol after isFocused  on second input.? mine is working.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is working now! Missed the exclamation mark on the containerStyle prop like you said. It does mean that when the screen loads the first input field is focussed which I  am looking to avoid.

Comment: so you want on load is both inputs are not focus?. means their style is the same when onload?

Comment: answer upadated.

Comment: This seems to then focus the first field when entering the second field and vice versa. Thanks for your help on this!